# Reading a specific column in a .tsv file

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to read data from a .tsv file into a vector. The file is structured something like this:

```
A    B
1    2
2    4
6    8
```

I want to ask what column the program should read, and then push the values from that column into a vector. My code so far is this:

```
int main() {

string filename, column, headerLine;
vector<double> data, tempData;
int numColumn;

ifstream dataFile;
cout << "enter a filename" << endl;
cin >> filename;
dataFile.open(filename);
cout << "enter a column name" << endl;
cin >> column;
cout << "reading column " << column << " from " << filename;
getline(dataFile, headers);

//here's where I feel stuck

}
```

If I can get the headers into a vector called headersList and then do something similar for the data rows, I would be able to do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < headersList.size(); i++) {
    if(headersList[i] == column) {
        numColumn = i;
    }
}
while(!dataFile.eof()) {
    //some way of getting the data points into a vector called tempData
    data.push_back(tempData[numColumn]);
    tempData.clear();
}
```

I'd really appreciate some help

Comment: Do you only have two columns? Is each header's name unique?

Comment: I have more than two columns, and yes, each header's name is unique. The names of the columns can also be more than 1 char in length, but will not contain a space

Comment: The datatype for the header doesn't seem to be a problem since you're comparing strings, I'll answer your question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
while(!dataFile.eof()) {
    std::string str;
    std::getline( dataFile, str);
    std::stringstream buffer(str);
    std::string temp;
    std::vector<double> values;

    while( getline( buffer, temp, '\t') ) {
        values.push_back( ::strtod(temp.c_str(), 0));
    }

    data.push_back(values[numColumn]);
}
```